# IPC: Shared memory killed process notfication

Tags: synchronization, ipc, shared-memory

In shared memory system, when two processes share a shared memory system, after one process is killed, how the other running process will be notified of killed process by shared memory system ?

Answer (score 1):

Shared memory, as the name suggests, is a *memory*, a passive object. You need to use a mutex to keep track of activity of another application. Each application creates its own mutex and waits for another process's one. If the application is terminated, the mutex state turns to Abandoned.

Comment: Thanks so much Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS.  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html for reference :  SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated

Comment: @mav_2k If you are talking about linux or Unix, you might need to reflect this by setting proper tags for your question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a parent/controlling process start all other processes as children.   When any child dies, the parent will receive [`SIGCHLD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) and can handle cleanup of shared memory/resources in a sane manner.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) follows this design pattern with its postmaster and worker processes.

Note that on most Unix systems, mutexes won't be changed/unlocked by the OS during process death.   Semaphores offer an UNDO function, but they are admittedly much heavier than mutexes.    YMMV.

Comment: Thanks so much CoreyStup.  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html for reference :  SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated